# Get Current Time in mm/dd/yyyy in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, mfc

I am using the following code for setting the time in a Date Control in MFC using C++

```
CTime date;
date = date.GetCurrentTime();
this->m_headerDate.SetTime(&date);
```

This will get the Date and set it to the control in what ever format the user machine uses. But I want to set it to a format of ONLY mm/dd/yyyy.
There should be some way of doing this in MFC. Are there any utility functions for this?

Thanks,

Comment: why not use ctime library it is already given to you

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about getting a specific textual representation of a date/time, you can use `strftime()` to format a date in many different ways, including the one specified in your question.

You will need a variable of type `time_t` using the facilities in the `ctime` header. So you can either switch to using those times, or I believe `CTime::GetTime( )` will give you one.

However, if you're talking about forcing a *control* to display it's date/time in a specific format, that's a property of the control itself. For example, `CDateTimeCtrl` provides a `SetFormat()` method which will modify how it displays its data.

Comment: if this Strptime() is in a different library? I prefer doing it with CTIME. I discovered a function in CTIME called Format which I am playing with if I can get the desired format irrespective of System's Date

Comment: @Sri, it's _standard_ C++, you just need to include the header. And you can continue to use `CTime` since it has a function that gives you the equivalent `time_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Without MFC:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int MAXLEN = 80;
    char s[MAXLEN];
    time_t t = time(0);
    strftime(s, MAXLEN, "%m/%d/%Y", localtime(&t));
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

[Compiled Code](http://ideone.com/r3SlQL)

With MFC:

This function formats a date as a date string for a specified locale. The function formats either a specified date or the local system date.

```
int GetDateFormat(
  LCID Locale, 
  DWORD dwFlags, 
  CONST SYSTEMTIME* lpDate, 
  LPCTSTR lpFormat, 
  LPTSTR lpDateStr, 
  int cchDate 
); 

change LPCTSTR lpFormat to MM:dd:yyyy
```

Comment: Is `GetDateFormat()` platform independent C++ code? Can I run this code to get system date in other OS?

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm storing value in a `CString` variable
Try this code:

```
CString strTime;
CTime date;
date = GetCurrentTime();
strTime = date.Format(_T("%m/%d/%Y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of doing this...not sure if this is the simplest way though
Since we already have a datetime control .All we can do is just use the Setformat Function of the DatetimeControl. PFB an example of this

```
    CDateTimeCtrl m_DateTimeCtrl;
    m_DateTimeCtrl.SetFormat(_T("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

The above will set it up to the format of 01/14/2015 which is desired. Thanks to Paxdiablo, Himanshu and  Irrational Person for the inputs. They did point me in right direction with different options.